# Redirect Linux terminal to clipboard

Tags: grep, clipboard

Is it possible to redirect the output of your terminal in linux to the clipboard?  Right now I am using Ubuntu 9.10 and I simply right click and "copy" the selected text.  It would be a lot easier if I could go like this...

```
grep sometext myfile || clipboard
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [xclip](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/xclip) package will do this.  Another similar tool that is also frequently useful is [pastebinit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/karmic/pastebinit).

Usage is simple just do something like `cat /etc/passwd | xclip`.

It is also possible, to take the contents of the clipboard and use it with a command like `xclip -out | grep 'foo'`.

Comment: This makes my day.

Comment: Thanks!  Glad to find this but somehow stunned that Linux doesn't have a standard program already installed for this....

Answer (score 3):

The command doesn't work just this way:

```
ls | xclip
```

You should use this variant to make it work:

```
ls | xclip -selection clipboard
```

hmm... rather long for such an easy task...

Comment: that worked for me can you explain why?